# Why is npm install react-router-dom not working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, npm-install, react-router-dom

It starts like this but never proceeds:

`[..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session c63c949f06e27b29`

Then after a while, it fails. This is the error message:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/react-router-dom failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-23T07_31_04_992Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what command you are running?

Comment: Either NPM is having issues, your computer's networking is having issues, or there are issues somewhere between your computer and NPM.

Comment: @Alvin.Kamau Kindly check below answer, It might be helpful

Comment: try using a vpn maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to incorrect proxy settings. Verify network proxy settings are correct.

Else try removing proxy settings using below commands and try again.

$ npm config rm proxy

$ npm config rm https-proxy

Comment: I have done that already but there seems to be no difference.